# Transfer sql server data to mysql database using program

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have an old system with sql server database. And I have to create a webiste with mysql database. The old system is still in use and is inserting data to the sql server DB everyday. So, I am thinking write a program that automatically transfer data from the sql server DB to the mysql DB. Any good suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way that Java can read data from sql server mdf database file. As the old sql server can produce mdf file everyday, I wonder can I use mdf file for the java website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a small (Maybe in c#) program that keeps running all the times with a timer, and on this timer, get all rows from SQL server that are not marked as "Copied", insert them on MySQL and the update those rows as "Copied". That program need to have access to both databases.

Answer (score 1):

You have an *active* SQL Server database.

Unless you are planning to decommission this database server (for *very good reasons* not related to this new application), then the new application should simply query this server.